# Global variable in makefile

Tags: gnu-make

I am trying to assign one unique number to each file which is getting compiled through make and sub makes. For this I exported the variable in top level make using `export varName = 1` and then this is getting incremented for each `.c` file which is compiled using following

```
$(eval varName=$(shell echo $$(($(varName)+1))))
```

Problem is `varName` is again initialized to `1` when the sub make file is called from the top level makefile.

How can I retain the last updated value while calling the sub makefiles?

Comment: Why do want to do this? There might be a better way.

Comment: I want to define user defined macros similar to standard predefined macros (__FILE__, __LINE__). __FILE__ macro gives the filename. Similar to this i want to implement something like __FILENUMBER which gives me the unique integer number for the file. I can assign this particular C file using -DFILE_NUMBER=fileNum. Here fileNum varies for each file which is getting compiled through Make. Any other suggestions were welcome. Thanks

Comment: So if, say, `foo.c` gets file-number 35, that means it was the 35th file to
be compiled in this make-run and you compile that number into `foo.o`? 
Well next time it might be the 168th file to be compiled. Or it might not be  compiled at all and `bar.c` gets number 35 instead, So now `foo.o` and `bar.o` both have number 35. I can't see how the idea makes sense.

Comment: these numbers need not be fixed and can be changed. Agree these number are fixed for a particular build and can be changed for different build.

Answer (score 0):

Exporting a variable just provides a copy with which the sub-make initializes its own separate table of variables. So, this won't allow write-back of value changes.

To create a truly global variable, you could call an external program or script which increments a counter persisted in a file or database table. However, this might lead into trouble, if your make sub-processes are started concurrently rather than sequentially. This would cause parallel access and thus probably a non-reproducible numbering sequence.

There are some [objections in general](https://www.google.de/search?q=recursive%20make%20harmful&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b&gfe_rd=cr&ei=t1JhV5H3FaGK8QeyvanwDw) against using sub-make. To create an additional external process per compilation would also lengthen your make time.